# InvalidOperationException: Connection string not found

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to run my ASP.NET Core MVC application but when I do, I get this error:

> options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Farah_O_Exercise_4Context") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'Farah_O_Exercise_4Context' not found.")));

[Here is the result after clicking a page on the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD51t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add your connection string in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"Farah_O_Exercise_4Context": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=yourDbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
```

Hope this help you!
Have a nice day :)